# what is the way to submit jobs via console to flink-standalone zookeeper-recovery-mode cluster?

Tags: mesos, apache-flink, marathon

I have a flink cluster configure for zookeeper recovery mode runing on marathon. What's the best practice for submit an application to flink cluster by console?[taskmanager log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By1V400SzzkbWTNmRk9nTENicU0)  ,[jobmanager log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By1V400SzzkbLWJUT0lLU0pEOUU)  and [client out](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By1V400SzzkbZzQtREdVdVZON0k)

Comment: Have you tried using Flink's CLI with the ZooKeeper configuration?

Comment: that's the problem, I can't get the right way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have to configure the `flink-conf.yaml` with the same ZooKeeper settings as you have used to start the cluster. Given that your ZooKeeper cluster is reachable under `zookeeer.foobar.com:2181` and you've set the Flink cluster id to `flinkCluster`, then you have to insert the following configuration settings into the `flink-conf.yaml`:

```
high-availability: zookeeper
high-availability.cluster-id: flinkCluster
high-availability.zookeeper.quorum: zookeeper.foobar.com:2181
```

### Update

The Flink version 1.2.x contains a bug which requires to set the `JobManager's` address and port via `jobmanager.rpc.address` and `jobmanager.rpc.port` in the `flink-conf.yaml`. Otherwise the `ClusterClient` fails with an exception or cannot retrieve the proper NIC with which it can talk to the remote `JobManager`. The problem is described by [FLINK-6629](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-6629).

Comment: yes,I did just that,but I get an error from the client:"Failed to retrieve the JobManager gateway".The problem is with my marathon app.Zookeeper assigns a different rcp port than the one assigned by Marathon to Flink container.I recently saw this,my mistake,sorry.I think that the client cant connect to the  jobmaner because the port ofered by zookeeper is not binded to host port given for marathon.To convince me,I tryed do the submit inside the taskmanager container but,I have the same error.I still can't understand how the taskmanajer can register to the jobmaner if the client can't.Any idea?

Comment: You can check the logs to see to which port the JobManager has bound to. In the client log you see which JobManager address it has retrieved for the connection attempt. This information would be helpful.

Comment: I saw the rcp port on the flink web, I also saw the same information in the taskmanager and jobmanager logs, the same port in all places, and I used that port for the client, but it did not work. If I use that port in the jobmanager's container everything works very well with the client, but, outside, I get the connection error.

Comment: Not only the port but also the address to which you bind is important. For the communication it must be exactly the same on the server and client side. Could you check that this is the case?

Comment: I have the taskmanager and the jobmanager configured to use zookeeper, both running in docker containers configured as marathon app. The taskmanager poll zookeeper and finds perfectly the jobmanager. With that same configuration I try to use "flink run -d" to run an app but I get the connection error. The port assigned by marathon for the rcp port does not match the one shown by Flink, however the taskmanager is registered correctly. Why can't the client do the same?

Comment: The address and port displayed by the client and the taskmanager during the connection is the same. I have checked it in all logs

Comment: Could you share all logs with? Ideally with log level on debug.

Comment: I edited my original ask with flink's logs and client output

Comment: It seems that this is a bug in Flink. I've updated my answer. Thanks for your patience and help with debugging the problem :-)

Comment: Ok, I hope I have been useful, thank you for your job guys

Comment: The fix should be merged in the next couple of hours.

Comment: What is the version of flink that contains the bug fixed?

Comment: 1.3.0 which has just been released contains the bug fix for this problem.

Comment: all right!!!!, "run command" with zookeeper configurations work fine in flink 1.3.0 version. I have prove it in windows and linux